# PHP: xml_parse replaces entities and "?" character

Tags: php, xml, rss

How can I describe something I can't quite put my finger on?
I have a module for RSS reading "magpierss" it uses xml_parse() and after extensive troubleshooting all I can come up with is that it removes certain entities like "?" character.

I haven't written this module myself but I have traced the code until the part uses xml_parse() and then the output is just replaced.

And to my disappointment this behavior exists on our production server only and not the local server.
I have compared both php.ini file to search for any differences but couldn't find anything.

Could anyone please direct on where to search exactly, i don't even know which direction to start from.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`mb_string` was enabled on the server
and somehow it produces this unexpected behavior with `xml_parse()`